# ¿Cómo puedo generar un link que me lleve a un vídeo de YouTube?

Tags: javascript, enlace, youtube

Quiero hacer una página que tome todas las canciones de una playlist sacada de Deezer, me cree un div por cada título y, al presionar en cada uno de estos, me lleve a la correspondiente canción pero en YouTube (algo así como hacen los bots de Discord, pero dando click en el elemento y no poniendo el nombre). Lo que no sé muy bien es cómo hacer esto último. ¿Cómo puedo, teniendo el título de una canción, generar un link que me lleve a dicha canción en la plataforma? ¿O no hay manera y tendría que ir inspeccionando los elementos de la página principal de YouTube, encontrar el buscador, poner el título y seleccionar el primer elemento?

Comment: Podrías usar un Selenium. Pero probablemente te sea más cómodo usar la [API de YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). Lo mismo para Deezer. Investiga como usar su API. Siempre es muy bueno usar una API antes que tener que recurrir a soluciones extrañas.

Comment: La API de Deezer la uso, de ahí obtengo la playlist. Pero para usar de YouTube, al parecer, necesito tener mi aplicación en una página con dominio y demás, cosa que no tengo porque es algo personal. Pensé en crear una página con Github Pages, pero allí solo puedo usar estáticas y esta, creo, no lo sería. ¿Sabes de alguna otra solución?

Comment: Que yo recuerde no necesitas ningún dominio. Quizá te refieras a añadir restricciones a tus credenciales. Eso es para minimizar la posibilidad de que se produzcan usos no autorizados de tus credenciales.

Comment: Tienes razón. Me confundí al ver que para usar la API y eso me pedía un dominio y demás, pero hasta en el localhost se puede. Muchas gracias